# PromQL usage of hour() in a range over midnight

Tags: metrics, promql

I'm trying to specifically return metrics between a certain timeslot. I'm trying to put an alert on a specific metric with different watermarks depending on being at night or during the day.

When I query the daytime metric it works fine: `sum(increase(some_counter_total[5m])) and hour() >4 <20`
This of course works as the `bigger than 4 but smaller than 23` is a valid range.

However, this becomes more interesting when one wants to do this during the night time, for the reverse timeslot: `sum(increase(some_counter_total[5m])) and hour() >20 <4`
The first condition `bigger then 20` already eliminates the following `smaller then 4`. The same is true when reversing the order.

I have tried some different combinations of using `or`, but I must be doing it wrong as I never got the querie to work properly. Ideally, I think I would be searching for a way to do a reverse query `sum(increase(some_counter_total[5m])) and WHEN NOT hour() >4 <20`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mind that Prometheus operates on data vectors. Try [negation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) (`and` vs. `unless`) to exclude the hours you don't want.

Day time:

```
sum(increase(some_counter_total[5m])) and hour() >=9 <21
```

Night time:

```
sum(increase(some_counter_total[5m])) unless hour() >=9 <21
```

---

This is probably not the most efficient solution, but I couldn't find another way such as your straightforward suggestion or something like `WHERE value IN (4, 5, 6, <...night time hours...>)`).

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks! Looks like I was over complicating this.